# How do you draw the World map with a correct India map using D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, choropleth, topojson

I am trying to create world map by using D3.js. The India map outlines are not correct. I am confused, should it be fixed via topo json values or via any other way.

[World map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFEow.png)

Here is my world map topo json file.

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-110m.json

Any suggestion appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to find a dataset that uses the borders you want to display - the file you have used contains de facto borders, consequently, you can't use this dataset to draw the map you want.